# HttpContent.ReadAsAsync method not returning correct value from a Web API call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

My WebAPI method returns a status code as well as a boolean value:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Register([FromBody]string parameter)
{
     HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
     RegisterUserResult result = await _service.RegisterAsync(parameter);
     if (result == RegisterUserResult.AlreadyExists)
     {
          statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
     }
     else if (result == RegisterUserResult.Created)
     {
          statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created;
     }
     return Request.CreateResponse(statusCode, true);
}
```

On client side, I call HttpContent.ReadAsAsync method to check the boolean value in the response after making the API call:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, parameter);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
     bool result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>(); // result is false!
     return result;
}
```

The problem is that *result* returns as **false**. What could I be missing?

Comment: Are you sure it's hitting that one return at end of your api and there are no other returns ?

Comment: When you check what is actually returned from your service how that response looks like?

Comment: Like what Alexei said, try hitting your WebApi with a tool like Postman and ensure that it's returning what you expect ("true").  Then you know if the issue is server-side or client.

Comment: Yes, I am debugging both client and server side and can confirm Request.CreateResponse(statusCode, true); is being hit on the server.
However, while debugging the client & server on a different machine, ReadAsAsync method DID return true on client - just once on the first try, then it was always false again :/

Comment: Okay, turns out the different HTTP status codes that I am returning, depending on the database action result, does have an impact on the issue so I updated my question to include that part as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that this happens because I am returning `HttpStatusCode.Created` for the initial action (user creation), however return `HttpStatusCode.NoContent` for subsequent actions on the same user.

```
if (result == RegisterUserResult.AlreadyExists)
{
     statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
}
```

While HttpStatusCode.NoContent is a successful status code, it will prevent providing a return value in **Request.CreateResponse** method by returning the **default value** of your intended return type. Meaning

```
Request.CreateResponse(statusCode, "True"); // returns null on client-side
Request.CreateResponse(statusCode, true); // returns false on client-side
```

Other success codes such as HttpStatusCode.OK or HttpStatusCode.Created will make sure that the intended value will be returned.